# Cordova unable to build APK with x86_64 lib folder

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, apk

**Problem**: when I build an APK file and upload it to google I get the "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement" error.

**Context**: I am bringing an app back up to speed after it sat neglected for a year and a half.

**General**: I have gone through the document that google provided and applied what I could. https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit. I have also built the APK then gone into android studio and verified that I am in fact missing the x86_64 lib folder.
[Screen shot of APK inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxzhp.png)

I took special care to include `ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'` in the App level build.gradle file. I also made sure that the target sdk was above 21.

At this point I am not sure what is causing this as it seem that Gradle is ignoring this line of code as the APK is the same with or without it.

**Environment**:

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\JMarshall\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.16.0\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (16 plugins total)

System:

NodeJS : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10

**App/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build 
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "../com-sarriaroman-photoviewer/myecfmg-photoviewer.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk/myecfmg-build-extras-sb.gradle"
apply from: "../cordova-support-google-services/myecfmg-build.gradle"
apply from: "../pushwoosh-cordova-plugin/myecfmg-build.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    //ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = project.ext.defaultCompileSdkVersion
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : defaultMinSdkVersion
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {

    defaultConfig {

        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    //This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    //By default, we multiply the existing version code in the Android Manifest by 10 and 
    //add a number for each architecture.  If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    //ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {

   flavorDimensions "default"
   productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
            ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'  
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:(+,17.0.0)"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:(+,19.0.0)"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:5.22.6"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-amazon:5.22.6"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-badge:5.22.6"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox:5.22.6"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox-ui:5.22.6"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
      if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
         promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
      }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}
```

**Android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
     // defaultMinSdkVersion=21 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** modify Cordova-generated gradle files like `platforms/android/app/build.gradle`.

Instead add your custom gradle configs in a separated file `platforms/android/app/build-extras.gradle`:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
    android.defaultConfig.ndk.abiFilters = ['armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64']
}
```

For more details about using `build-extras.gradle` in Cordova please see the docs [Configuring Gradle](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle).

Then make sure to clean and rebuild the android project:

```
cd platforms/android/
./gradlew app:clean
cd ../../
ionic cordova build android
```

After a successful build unzip and check the `lib` content of the APK, like

```
jar xfv platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk lib
ls -la lib/
```

or use the APK inspector.

BTW: Check out the new and highly recommended [Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle) approach to reduce the final APK and app size. Alternatively, consider checking whether you really need x86 + x86_64 support in your app.